# How can I stop media player in array adapter when user leaves the screen?

Tags: android, arrays

I have racked my brain and looked around online but I cant seem to find an answer to my issue. I managed to create an app that plays audio files generated by a custom array adapter. I want the audio to stop playing when the user leaves the screen.

I see people use the onStop method if the media player is created in an activity. Mine is created in the array adapter class which does not allow the use of the onStop method. Please help :)

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // Now that the sound file has finished playing, release the media player resources.
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};

//Define constructor which takes 2 arguments i.e the Context and the list of words.
public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
    super(context, 0, words);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;
    if (listItem == null)
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    /* Get the item from list of words in the adapter and pass the position as argument*/
    Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    ImageButton play = (ImageButton) listItem.findViewById(playButton);

    final int audioResourceId = currentWord.getAudioResourceId();

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View play) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), audioResourceId);
            mediaPlayer.start();

            // Setup a listener on the media player, so that we can stop and release the
            // media player once the sound has finished playing.
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
        }
    });
    /* Return the generated view */
    return listItem;
}

public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
        // because we no longer need it.
        mediaPlayer.release();

        // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
        // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
        // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should leave the `MediaPlayer` in the Activity that contains the `ListView` and in your `WordAdapter` class implement a `Listener`. use it in your `onClick()` method sending the `audioResourceId` you need for the player.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. Is there a reason why it is bad practice to have it in the adapter?

Comment: In order to stop your media player you need to reference the object directly. Your media player is in you adapter and for that reason it is not directly accessible through the `onStop` method.